# Using APT on an isolated network with a proxy or mirror

Tags: apt, proxy, mirrors

I'm going to be deploying a number of x86_64 machines running Ubuntu 16.04 on an isolated IP network. I will have VPN access to the network, but the network will otherwise not have internet access.

My primary concern about this setup is being able to install updates on the machines on the network. For example, if there's a new version of the kernel released after I install Ubuntu on the machine and place it on the network, then it's important that there's some way to install the new version of the kernel on the machine. Ideally, I'd like to be able to use `apt update && apt upgrade` (or some variant) to install these updates.

These are the possible solutions I'm currently considering:

1. Use a machine on the isolated network as a HTTP proxy: this is the solution I would prefer as it's very straightforward to set up, but I'm not sure if it'll even be possible, or if it would be a security policy violation.
2. Use a machine on the isolated network as a local APT mirror/repository: this solution might work better since it's probably easy to configure APT to use a mirror, although it might be more of a pain because I'll need to figure out how to install the mirrored packages (and other required files) to the mirror, whenever there are updates available. I figure it would make the most sense to schedule this action on a regular basis.

I already know how to set up the first solution, but I doubt that it is going to be allowed by the network operator. I expect that the second solution is the better one for this reason; how would I go about setting that up?  What would such a system require? Alternatively, is there some other solution that might work better?

Comment: If the network is truly isolated, and if the hardware functions properly, then why the need for updates?

Comment: Even though the network is supposed to be isolated, we still need to be running the latest version of each software package installed to be compliant with security policies.

Comment: In Ubuntu, 'properly patched' does not mean 'latest version'. Example, a vuln in Foo 15 may be cause Foo upstream to release Foo 16 and tell everybody to upgrade. However, Ubuntu will use the Foo-provided patch and re-release as Foo 15.1. Ubuntu has good longstanding reasons to do this...but will your IT folks have heartburn because the version, while properly patched and addressing all CVEs, is not 'latest'?

Comment: That's good to know - if the question comes up, I'll be sure to explain that. Thanks! I think that as long as we're using the latest version made available by the package maintainers, then we'll be in good shape.